# Keep hover area from disappering

Tags: html, css, hover

[video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oPUqQn5Fyok) - how to keep area that displays on hover from disappearing?

Thank you

Comment: Uhm, by adding a `display: block` or whatever you use to unhide it on the element you are hovering over (so instead of just `parent:hover child { show }`, do `parent:hover child, child:hover { show }`)? But this is really minimal. Could you reduce your code to a simple example and post that so we can tell you what exactly is tripping you up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only provide very minimal code (*what am I saying? I mean **none**...*) and the video does't help code-wise, but I can suggest a solution for the problem I think you're having, namely that you are moving off the hover image and therefore the hovered box is hidden.

Instead of just showing a `child` div when hovering over the `parent`, show the `child` div when hovering over the `parent` *and* when hovering over the `child`. This means the child will only be hidden once you move off the `parent` *and* the `child`, but the `child` will be displayed as soon as you hover over the just the `parent`.

#### Example HTML

```
<parent>
    Hover over this...
    <child>.. to show this.</child>
</parent>
```

#### Example CSS

```
parent child {
    display: none;
}
parent:hover child,
parent child:hover {
    display: block;
}
```

Now your hover will continue until you left both elements, hiding the `child` again so it can therefore not trigger the hover until it is triggered by the `parent`.